# Does every ring have a subring that is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Well, that question arose at the very moment I saw two examples. The first one was about an integrity domain which has a subring that is a field (I don't remember the specific example) and the second one is:

Let $M = M_2(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all $2 \times 2$ matrixes with entries in $\mathbb{R}$ and $1_M = \left[\begin{array}[cc] &1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right] $. The set $A = \left\{a \in \mathbb{R};\left[\begin{array}[cc] &a & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right]\right\} \subset M$ is a subring of $M$ with unity $1_A = \left[\begin{array}[cc] &1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right] \neq \left[\begin{array}[cc] &1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right] = 1_M$. Furthermore, since $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, $A$ is a field.

So, there can be subrings with different unities than the ring they are subsets to. The question is, if a ring does not have unity and none of the other properties, there can be a subring that has unity?

Or if it is possible, can someone give me an example of a ring without unity that has a subring with unity?

And an example of a ring with no additional properties that has a subring that is a field?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Instead use $$A = \{ \begin{pmatrix} a \\ & a \end{pmatrix} a \in \mathbb R\}$$ which is a subring which has the same multiplicative identity as $M_2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: The ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ has unity $1$, I want an example of a ring without unity that has a subring with unity.

Comment: Dietrich, the question is similar, but still the $\mathbb{Z}_n$ have unit, the element $\overline{1}$. I don't know the translation from portuguese to english of "corpos" (literal translation is "bodies"), which are commutative rings with unit, without dividers of 0 and multiplicative inverses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R = \mathbb R \times 2\mathbb Z$.  Since $2\mathbb Z = \{ 2n : n \in \mathbb Z \}$ does not have a multiplicative identity, neither does $R$.  However, $R$ contains $\{ (x,0) : x \in \mathbb R\}$ as a subring which is a field, isomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Great answer man. Which operations are defined on $R$?

Comment: Pointwise addition and multiplication: $(a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (ac,bd)$ and the same for addition.

Comment: Cool. So it is a commutative ring with no dividers of $0$? Do you know if a ring without additional properties can have a subring that is a field?

Also, thank you! You've already helped a lot :)

Comment: What "additional properties" do you mean?

Comment: The unity, commutativity of product, no dividers of 0 and multiplicative inverses.

Comment: But combining my example and yours I've found one that satisfies my conditions: $R = M_2(\mathbb{R}) \times 4 \cdot \mathbb{Z}$. I can't thank you enough!! :)